# Change image position with Button

Tags: ios, button, uiview, position

I would want to change the position of an image in three different positions using a button...
With my code the image is only moved of a position...

ViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Switch3Way;

- (IBAction)Switch3WayPressed:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)Switch3WayPressed:(id)sender {
CGRect frame = Switch3Way.frame;
frame.origin.x = 323;
frame.origin.y = 262;
Switch3Way.frame = frame;
```

}

Comment: So what's your question? Is that code working? What results are you getting?

Comment: With my code the image is only moved of a position...

Comment: You mean that with your code the image is moving only to one position? and you want to move the image to other two positions?

Comment: Yes, in three different position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code assumes you want to animate your Switch3Way UIImageView IBOutlet property.  This code snippet will move your UIImageView to three different locations and stop the animation at the last position.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>    

-(IBAction)move:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint firstPosition = CGPointMake(someXvalue, someYvalue);
    CGPoint secondPosition = CGPointMake(someXvalue, someYvalue);
    CGPoint thirdPosition  = CGPointMake(someXvalue, someYvalue);

    CABasicAnimation *posOne = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    posOne.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:_Switch3Way.layer.position];
    posOne.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:firstPosition];
    posOne.beginTime = 0;
    posOne.duration  = 1;

    CABasicAnimation *posTwo = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    posTwo.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:firstPosition];
    posTwo.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:secondPosition];
    posTwo.beginTime = 1;
    posTwo.duration  = 1;

    CABasicAnimation *posThree = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    posThree.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:secondPosition];
    posThree.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:thirdPosition];
    posThree.beginTime = 2;
    posThree.duration  = 1;

    CAAnimationGroup *anims = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    anims.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:posOne, posTwo, posThree, nil];
    anims.duration = 3;
    anims.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    anims.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [_Switch3Way.layer addAnimation:anims forKey:nil];

    _Switch3Way.layer.position = thirdPosition;
}
```

Invasivecode has a pretty good series of tutorials on creating animations like you are referring to http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/4448661320/core-animation-part-iii-basic-animations You will eventually want to use CAKeyframeAnimation objects to create these types of animations, but understanding CABasicAnimations is a good way to start creating animations with CoreAnimation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify the requirement as to why you need to move the button to three different places? Anyways, I hope you will do the change based on some logic- so define three enums in the header file, e.g. something like the following:

```
typedef enum {
buttonState1,
buttonState2,
buttonState3
} buttonState;
```

Then, as per your business logic requirement, set these enum variables at the proper place in your code, e.g. something like the following:

```
-(void)setButtonState{

buttonState = buttonState1;

}
```

Now, in your button touch-up-inside handler routine, use a switch statement to set the appropriate frame, e.g. something like the following:

```
- (void)Switch3WayPressed:(id)sender {
    if (![sender isKindOfClass:[Switch3Way class]])
    return;
 switch (buttonState)

 {
 case buttonState1:
      {
      CGRect frame = Switch3Way.frame;
      frame.origin.x = 323;
      frame.origin.y = 262;
      Switch3Way.frame = frame;
      break;
   }
 case buttonState2:
      //some other rect origin based on your logic
      break;
 case buttonState3:
      //some other rect origin based on your logic
      break;
 default:
      break;

 }
```

Comment: Writing the code these errors happen…

   buttonState = buttonState1; - expected identifier or '(' -


switch (buttonState) - Unexpected type name'button state':expected expression...

Comment: @Subzero, The reason for which I want to move the image in three position is in order to create a simple animation...